# Console Error in Fullpage JS for html5 video

Tags: html5-video, fullpage.js

i am getting error in console "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first." in jquery.fullPage.js:1645 . i am using html5 video in my page and video is loading after some refreshes, sometimes video don't load. Anyone have some idea why its happening? where i am making mistake?

if( element.hasAttribute('data-autoplay') && typeof element.play === 'function' ) {
                    element.play(); //this is where i am landing when click on console error
                }

Comment: It is impossible to help you unless you provide a reproduction of your issue. Ideally isolated.
You should consider reading my post regarding [how to ask questions to get answers](https://alvarotrigo.com/blog/how-not-suck-at-asking-coding-questions/).

Comment: I have the url where in console one can see the error or warning, this may help I guess http://justcreativestuffs.com/demo/site/

Comment: You are not even initialising fullpage.js. I see the message `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullpage is not a function`

Comment: Create a jsfiddle for an isolated reproduction.